# Chrome: Scroll on <select> triggers change() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a `<select>` element with the `multiple="multiple"` attribute. In Chrome (v27), the `change()` event is getting triggered when the user *scrolls by clicking and dragging using the mouse*. Once a value has been selected, the problem ceases to exist.

#### Example Markup

```
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

#### Example jQuery

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  alert('Changed!');
});
```

Is this a bug with Chrome? I've tried [searching](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=chrome+select+scroll+triggers+change&oq=chrome+select+scroll+triggers+change) but haven't come across anything.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvQYN/)

Comment: I can't replicate it in Chrome (also v27)

Comment: @Zenith really? I'm using v27.0.1453.94m (apparently the latest version) and Windows 7 (though I didn't think the OS would be applicable)

Comment: @billyonecan I'm exactly the same version and on Windows 7 too :/ weird

Comment: @Zenith that's very strange indeed :|

Comment: @billyonecan i am using Version 27.0.1453.94 m with Windows7 can't replicate either. But seems to be a bug looking at PSR answer.

Comment: @Zenith I've noticed it only happens when actually clicking the scrollbar to scroll

Comment: @billyonecan In that case, I can replicate it :) PSR's answer is correct.

Comment: @billyonecan maybe `'click keyup'` be a replacement for `change` to prevent that bug, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvQYN/2/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is the bug in chrome

[`SELECT box with MULTIPLE option fires ONCHANGE event on scroll`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=244406)

and [`here`](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chromium-bugs/RL6LkT-KccA)

Comment: It's not just the MULTIPLE option. The SIZE option (with a value greater than 1) also triggers this bug.